# How can I use many time relationship one to many?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many

I'm creating API with JPA and Hibernate connected with MySQL databaze. I have objects "Exercise" which are saved in database and objects "Training". Exercise is simple, have name, id, level etc. but Training have id, name and listOfExercises. Best way to save it in database is using relationship one to many, right? But when I create training and connect it with for example "Push Ups" and "Squad" and next I create second training connected to the same exercises - owner is repleced. How can I create trainings and connect exercises with trainings without replacement?

Training model(constructors, getters and setters are also of course):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Training")
public class Training {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "training_id")
    private Long trainingId;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "training_id")
    private List<Exercise> exerciseList;

    @Column(name = "sets")
    @NotNull
    private int sets;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long userId;

    @Column(name = "training_name")
    @NotNull
    private String trainingName;

    @Column(name = "breaks")
    @NotNull
    private int breaksBetweenExercises;

    @Column(name = "level")
    @NotNull
    private int level;
```

Exercise model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Exercise")
public class Exercise {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "exercise_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "exercise_name")
    @NotNull
    private String exerciseName;

    @Column(name = "exercise_level")
    @NotNull
    private int level;

    @Column(name = "exercise_info")
    @NotNull
    private String info;

    @Column(name = "img_path")
    @NotNull
    private String imgPath;

    @Column(name = "reps")
    private int reps;
```

In this way I'm adding trainings:

```
        trainingRepository.save(new Training(exerciseRepository.findAll(),"Full Body Workout",5,1,4));

        List<Exercise> exercises = new ArrayList<>();
        exercises.add(exerciseRepository.findAll().get(2));
        exercises.add(exerciseRepository.findAll().get(1));
        trainingRepository.save(new Training(exercises,"Abs",10,2,4));
```

That's looks like in database (training_id is repleced):
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWPFf.jpg)

Comment: Maybe many to many relationship?

Comment: Can you please provide some code?

Comment: @Amongalen I'm new with databases, many to many should work?
 I added my models

Comment: put it this way, user is enrolled in training and training has many exercises, further multiple users can have same training.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pawel, In your case you should use Many-To-Many relationship. If you are new to the databases you can simply imagine the relation like this - push-ups (exercise) can be a part of Many trainings, and in the same time a training (for example HIIT) can have Many exercises. In the Database this relationship is being implemented with additional table - lets say ExcersisesToTrainings Table. In that Table you will see a composite key (two columns - training_id and exercise_id). In the example you will find the ID of the "Push_Ups" (lets say id=1) in many rows with different Training IDs, and in the same time you will find the ID of the HIIT training in many rows mapped to different exercise IDs. When you use ORM, that table will be created for you automatically.